# Question about Liferay DXP Forms: When are they the best choice?

Tags: forms, liferay, liferay-7, formbuilder, liferay-dxp

I have a question that requires clarification. It would be greatly appreciated if someone from the Liferay team could answer it: When is it appropriate to use Liferay Forms, and when is it not?

We acknowledge that Liferay Forms is an excellent choice and a powerful tool for creating simple forms with basic fields and collecting data from customers or leads on the portal. We understand that Liferay is working to improve the Form Builder.

However, I am currently working on a complex application that requires multiple validations, integrations, popups, previews, payment integration, customer review pages, and rich user interfaces. Given these requirements, I am unsure whether to use Liferay Forms or custom modules.

Can Liferay Forms handle such complex requirements without limitations?

Answer (score 0):

The tried and true method is to use custom modules. [React portlets](https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017888032-Using-React-in-Your-Portlets) with [Java OSGi REST services](https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360028748872-Generating-APIs-with-REST-Builder) will do the trick.

More modern is the new [remote apps](https://liferay.dev/blogs/-/blogs/remote-apps-how-to-use-liferay-7-4-new-feature-) way: build your web app with whatever tech stack you want and "publish" them into Liferay as "remote app" / "web component". This will be easier for you when you want to upgrade Liferay to a newer version (and there's one every week)

HTH